# How can I cache nuget packages in Github actions for multiple docker builds in a single workflow?

Tags: docker, github, caching, nuget, github-actions

I want to cache nuget packages across multiple docker builds. We, at times, run 20 docker builds so it'll help reduce the build times.

I ultimately want to use Github's `actions/cache` so the cache for nuget packages is stored in Github's cache memory. This way the cache can be used across multiple runs for the same workflow.

This is what I tried:

- Use `--mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages` to mount the cache folder
- Cache the `/root/.nuget/packages/` directory under `actions/cache`. This didn't work and github runner gave me permission denied error for accessing `/root` folder.
- I tried caching the `~/.nuget/packages` folder also but it didn't have anything to cache so that failed too.

Which directory should I look for to cache nuget packages? Is there something wrong with the way I'm using BuildKit's `--mount feature`.

Comment: What did the cache action look like for the `~/.nuget/packages` attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your workflow file is, but this works for me:

```
name: Job Name

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Install .NET 6.0
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x

      - name: Cache NuGet Packages
        id: nuget-packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        env:
          cache-name: nuget-package-cache
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ env.cache-name }}

      - name: List NuGet Packages
        if: ${{ steps.nuget-packages.outputs.cache-hit == 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: ls -lh ~/.nuget/packages

      - name: .NET Publish
        run: dotnet publish ....
```